# Integration of STB tester with appium

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, appium, stb-tester

I want to integrate *STB tester* with *Appium* so that I can automate video validation test cases of my app. Could anyone give me some tips where to start?

I have setup *STB tester* and *Appium*. What steps should I do next to proceed further?

Comment: Are you sure that stb tester is compatible with appium?

Comment: No we are not sure we are just trying

Comment: Actually I have not heard regarding this combination as appium is only for mobile application so.

Comment: Yes appium is only for mobile app we want to automate mobile app only which is related to video such as media player mobile tv or youtube mobile app so validating video video quality we need stp tester along with appium

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand correctly STB tester captures video only through HDMI- is your app and device capable of that ?

If yes than you could probably ignore the remote control part of the tester or send dummy commands, then just use the analyzed video results in parallel to appium.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of integrating stb-tester and Selenium: [Add visual verification to your Selenium tests with stb-tester](https://stb-tester.com/blog/2016/09/20/add-visual-verification-to-your-selenium-tests-with-stb-tester).  Both Selenium and Appium use Webdriver to interact with the device under test, so you may find this article useful.

You say you're trying to automate testing of a mobile app that is video based.  You may find our article [Testing Video Playback on Mobile Devices](https://stb-tester.com/blog/2017/02/21/testing-video-playback-on-mobile-devices) relevant.